# Passing variables from AWSShellScript task to a bash script task (Azure DevOps, pipelines)

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

My pipeline is about running E2E Allure tests, and uploading a report on the tests. I have created a webhook on Teams, as I'm trying to pass the result of the E2E test step and the report URL to a channel on Teams. This is a part of my pipeline

```
parameters:
  ...

jobs:
  - job: E2ETests
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'skip ci')))
    displayName: E2E Tests
    pool: xxx-$(ENV_NAME)-e2e

    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: E2ETests

      ...

      - task: AWSShellScript@1
        displayName: E2E tests
        name: e2etests
        condition: and(succeeded(), not(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'skip ci')))
        inputs:
          awsCredentials: $(AWS_CONNECTION_NAME)
          regionName: $(REGION)
          scriptType: "inline"
          continueOnError: true
          inlineScript: |
            ...

      - task: AWSShellScript@1
        displayName: Upload Allure report
        name: upload_allure_report8
        condition: always()
        inputs:
          awsCredentials: $(IT_CONNECTION_NAME)
          regionName: $(REGION)
          scriptType: "inline"
          inlineScript: |
            ...
            export REPORT_URL=https://${ALLURE_S3_BUCKET}/${{parameters.ALLURE_REPORT_ENV}}/$(Build.BuildNumber)/index.html
            echo Report URL: ${REPORT_URL}
            ...
```

Now, I have made numerous attempts at passing the status of e2etests step and the report url within upload_allure_report8. The most coherent one is

```
      - script: |
          MESSAGE='{
            "text": "E2E tests have finished. Status: $(result.e2etests.outcome). Report URL: $(REPORT_URL)"
          }'
          curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$MESSAGE" $(WEBHOOK)
        condition: always()
        displayName: 'Send Microsoft Teams Notification'
```

The webhook works, as my channel receives the message. But it looks like this:

```
E2E tests have finished. Status: . Report URL:
```

I have tried echoing those values from a separate script block, to having it under the report upload step, but all the same - from within the pipeline logs, it would throw `command not found`. Now, this is quite confusing, as I have tried a ton of match ups - lower case, short hand, full path, it all ends the same. Do note that the actual pipeline works - I can see the report url from within the report upload step. But as soon as I try to pass them to the script, its as if they don't exist. But it's possible I'm passing them wrong. Also to note, I have tried a ton of different matchups using ChatGPT, which also wasn't helpful. Any guidance very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Changes to environment variables are not persisted across steps. Please review the documentation on how to set runtime variables and access them in subsequent jobs.